# Run ML prediction for 100 new (synthetic) items

Tags: python

I am trying to develop an application that will suggest exercises I can perform before any workout routine.

I have created the below dataset, which captures routines (tagged as R_IDs) and corresponding exercises (tagged as E_IDs). The attributes are all the columns that follow. The last column 'Used' is a condition that classifies whether the exercise was selected for that particular routine (as 1) or not (as 0).

| E_ID | ER_ID | R_ID | exercise_ID | variation_ID | equipment_ID | weight_ID | occurence_1 | occurence_2 | occurence_3 | occurence_4 | occurence_5 | Used |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 442 | 2 | 0.0 | 95.0 | 6 | 6 | 3 | 0 | 0.0 | 0.0 | 0.0 | 0.0 | 0.0 |
| 443 | 5 | 0.0 | 95.0 | 6 | 6 | 6 | 1 | 52.0 | 42.0 | 10.0 | 8.0 | 0.0 |
| 444 | 7 | 0.0 | 95.0 | 7 | 7 | 3 | 0 | 90.0 | 82.0 | 71.0 | 66.0 | 57.0 |
| 445 | 8 | 0.0 | 95.0 | 7 | 7 | 6 | 1 | 0.0 | 0.0 | 0.0 | 0.0 | 0.0 |
| 446 | 9 | 0.0 | 95.0 | 7 | 7 | 5 | 3 | 66.0 | 0.0 | 0.0 | 0.0 | 0.0 |
| 447 | 12 | 0.0 | 95.0 | 2 | 6 | 1 | 3 | 64.0 | 38.0 | 5.0 | 0.0 | 0.0 |
| 448 | 14 | 0.0 | 95.0 | 0 | 6 | 0 | 3 | 79.0 | 75.0 | 66.0 | 57.0 | 46.0 |

I am trying to run the code for 100 routines into the future, to check if the code identifies logical set of exercises.

```
# List of Exercises
exercise_list = exercise_df[exercise_df['Sub part'].isin(sub_parts_selected)]['E_ID'].dropna().unique()
new_row = []
routine_count = merged_df['R_ID'].max() + 5

for x in range (100):
    routine_count = routine_count + x
    for i in exercise_list:
        new_row = {'E_ID' : i,
                   'ER_ID' : None,
                   'R_ID' : routine_count,
                   'exercise_ID' : merged_df[merged_df['E_ID']==i]['exercise_ID'].values[0],
                   'variation_ID' : merged_df[merged_df['E_ID']==i]['variation_ID'].values[0],
                   'equipment_ID' : merged_df[merged_df['E_ID']==i]['equipment_ID'].values[0],
                   'weight_ID' : merged_df[merged_df['E_ID']==i]['weight_ID'].values[0],
                   'occurence_1' : 0,
                   'occurence_2' : 0,
                   'occurence_3' : 0,
                   'occurence_4' : 0,
                   'occurence_5' : 0,
                   'Used' : 100}
        merged_df.loc[len(merged_df)] = new_row

        # Assess the last set of routines when the exercise was performed
        merged_df.loc[(merged_df['Used'].isin([1, 100])) & (merged_df['E_ID'] == i), 'occurence_1'] = merged_df.loc[merged_df['Used'].isin([1, 100])].groupby('E_ID')['R_ID'].shift(1)
        merged_df.loc[(merged_df['Used'].isin([1, 100])) & (merged_df['E_ID'] == i), 'occurence_2'] = merged_df.loc[merged_df['Used'].isin([1, 100])].groupby('E_ID')['R_ID'].shift(2)
        merged_df.loc[(merged_df['Used'].isin([1, 100])) & (merged_df['E_ID'] == i), 'occurence_3'] = merged_df.loc[merged_df['Used'].isin([1, 100])].groupby('E_ID')['R_ID'].shift(3)
        merged_df.loc[(merged_df['Used'].isin([1, 100])) & (merged_df['E_ID'] == i), 'occurence_4'] = merged_df.loc[merged_df['Used'].isin([1, 100])].groupby('E_ID')['R_ID'].shift(4)
        merged_df.loc[(merged_df['Used'].isin([1, 100])) & (merged_df['E_ID'] == i), 'occurence_5'] = merged_df.loc[merged_df['Used'].isin([1, 100])].groupby('E_ID')['R_ID'].shift(5)

        merged_df.fillna(0, inplace=True)

        predict_val = merged_df.drop (['ER_ID', 'Used'], axis = 1)
        predict_val = predict_val[predict_val['E_ID'] == 5][predict_val['R_ID'] == 95]
        try:
            merged_df.loc[(merged_df['E_ID'] == i) & (merged_df['Used'] == 100), 'Used'] = rf.predict(predict_val)[0]
        except ValueError:
            merged_df.loc[(merged_df['E_ID'] == i) & (merged_df['Used'] == 100), 'Used'] = 0
```

**I am running into the below issues:**

1. The code does not generate the few exercises for 100 new routines, as expected. There seems to be something wrong with the loop logic.
2. The random forest prediction model throws the below exception message:

```
"UserWarning: Boolean Series key will be reindexed to match DataFrame index.
 predict_val = predict_val[predict_val['E_ID'] == 5][predict_val['R_ID'] == 95]"
```

I know that the prediction logic can be improved, but that is for later. Any help on the above two points would be very helpful!